# Display html in jasper reports (static) text field

Tags: jasper-reports

I have this text in a static text field in jasper reports jrxml

```
<div style='width: 200px;height: 200px; border: 5px solid red; background-color:red'></div>
```

If I style the field as 'None', i can see the raw html in preview, however, if I style it as html, then nothing is displayed all all.  Obviously its a 200px x 200px red box with a black 5px border. Is there something i can do to have this html displayed inpreview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markup is responsible for text representation only. There is only a limited set of supported markup tags listed at [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/styledtext/index.html):

- `<b>`
- `<u>`
- `<i>`
- `<font>`
- `<sup>`
- `<sub>`
- `<li>`
- `<br>`

As you can see they are all related to text formatting.

If you need a red square you can draw it manually by adding rectangle with needed background color and border. Lightly modified example of rectangle element from the same guide:

```
  <rectangle>
    <reportElement x="0" y="350" width="200" height="200" backcolor="#ff0000"/>
    <graphicElement>
      <pen lineWidth="2"/>
    </graphicElement>
  </rectangle>
```

Comment: Notice these tags are available when `markup="styled"`. Quoting the linked page: _"The JasperReports proprietary markup language is called styled text and is an XML based format in which the style of any portion of text inside a text element can be changed by embedding that portion inside a <style> tag or other simple HTML tag from the following list:"_  There is an additional option of `markup="html"`; I am not sure how well it interprets valid/modern HTML, but it seems the OP tried it and didn't work for his specific markup.